# Scroll Bar in div

Tags: html, image, html-table

I have one div inside which I have one table. In this table as you can see there is one image tag. By Javascript I am setting the image src and displaying.
My problem is, if the image is large the div must scroll, but it is not scrolling.

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:640px;overflow:auto;">
<table frame="box" width="600px" height="330px">
  <tr>
    <td><img id="graphId" style="display:none" src="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is not scrolling because you have given fixed width and height for table. try with removing the height and width of the table. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `<img>`'s size is always zoomed to fit in `<td>`.

Here I'll show you how to use `overflow` in the right way.

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .scroll{overflow:scroll;width:500px;height:500px;background:black}
    .child{width:1000px;height:1000px;background:yellow}
</style>
```

[Demo on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FJhZ8/)

Comment: How to set my image size in div so that it fit inside thid div.
Right now image is coming on the left side of div. I want image to come in the middle .  Watch this image how it is coming :- http://i.imgur.com/6xBjJ.png

Answer (score 1):

try defining the height and width of the div...

http://jsfiddle.net/qyFTt/2/

Answer (score 1):

Change `overflow:auto;` to `overflow:scroll;` in your div style attribute.

Definition for [scroll](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp):

> The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of
>   the content